# How can I list the LAG offet for a specific topic and groupID

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I list the LAG offet for a specific topic and groupID.
Fow now I would like to compose a tool in java , to show that the current offset and LAG for a kafka topic and GroupId.
ANd this toll can be used as a library so that  I dont think the kafka check offset command line is my solution .
Moreover , I dont want to start a consumer for doing this , because this consumer will join the group and assigned with patitions , it is Intrusive
Any one please tell me is there any tool/API that I can use for doing this please ？》？

my kafka version is 
`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

`

Comment: With that version of Kafka, you'd need a Zookeeper client

Comment: Does the kafka-consumer-groups command not cover this need already?

Comment: All I need is how to embbed this function instead of calling a external command

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I think I didn't made myself cleared